# ubnutu 16.04 laravel virtual host not working even doing all steps as described

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04, hosting, installation-package

Laravel project in ubuntu 16.04 and with steps to create virtual host as mentioned but not working even serving on different port or without serve.

My system is ubuntu 16.04 with mode rewrite enabled and in apache2.conf allow override all at below location : 
    /var/www/html/study/forum

Below is my project conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dipaks_id@yahoo.co.in
    ServerName www.forum.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/study/forum/public

<Directory /var/www/html/study/forum/public/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # Change this "proxy:unix:/path/to/fpm.socket"
        # if using a Unix socket
        #SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp.com-error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Below is my /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   dipak-Inspiron-560s
127.0.1.1   www.forum.dev
192.168.0.7 www.forum.dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you own the `forum.dev` domain?

The `.dev` domain is [no longer able can be used](https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd) in develop environment. Try using `.local` or other domains.

Comment: changes from .dev to local and a2dissite forum.conf and again a2ensite forum.conf and while point to forum.local 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Thanks Cloud Soh Jun Fu, After changing http://www.laravel-forum.local/ I've made it working. Thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

The .dev domains only works on HTTPS (port 443). Your VirtualHost is set with HTTP (port 80). Check https://get.dev/#benefits

You need to install a SSL certificate and configure your VirtualHost with 443 port.

Check this tutorial on DigitalOcean's community:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks for your reply vegadavid, but we want quick development project in local and its only virtual host we are using for internal use, there is no such domain purchased and we will follow your steps in future if we want such domain. Thanks for valuable answer